# Android - ICS Settings Adapter

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, adapter

Is there any kind of predefined adapter or custom utility that can help me quickly create a ListView of settings that feels like the native ICS one?

I've read this document extensively:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html#flow-structure

And understand it perfectly, but it seems like a bit of work to roll my own ListView adapter that handles big dividers, and thin ones, and different size headers, etc. Googling isn't yielding many programming oriented results, mostly just items for end users, like how to use the settings in ICS.

**EDIT:** Browsing [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/Settings.java) seems to indicate that there is a large custom adapter embedded within the Settings App, in Settings.java ( the app entry point ).

Still though, I believe my question still stands, as I'd still like to either get an extracted version of that Adapter, or a tutorial for working with it or a custom one.

**EDIT 2:** Perhaps I should extend [PreferenceActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java).

**EDIT 3:** Perhaps extending won't work, as I'm using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), so I have to extend SherlockActivity.

Comment: Have you extended SherlockPreferenceActivity?

Comment: @BertB.: Do you have a link to that? I've not come across it, and searching only seems to give tracked issues for it.

Comment: I haven't personally used it, but I came across this conversation between the creator and someone in a similar position as you https://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock/browse_thread/thread/e35d6fcd82e9d060

And this is the github page for it https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockPreferenceActivity.java

Comment: @BertB.: Thanks a lot! Rafael pointed out that it's in the samples demo, which I completely skimmed over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation on [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: @Rafeal: I'm not sure that's relative to my question. I've already read most of that site, and have successfully implemented ABS throughout my app. I only mention it as it poses a conflict between itself and PreferenceActivity.

Comment: I use ABS, and the demos show some stuff close to what you want to do. [ABS Samples](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html)

Comment: Oh my, I don't know how I skipped over that section of the demo. Thanks!